# How to convert classification results into a leveled factor

Tags: r, classification, type-conversion

I have a "label.csv" file that consists of 0 and 1.

```
y = read.csv("./data/labels.csv", stringsAsFactors = T)
```

When I `cbind` `y` with the data and do classification training, the following warning appears:

```
Warning message:
In train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) :
  You are trying to do regression and your outcome only has two possible values Are you trying to do classification? If so, use a 2 level factor as your outcome column.
```

I want to convert `y` to a leveled factor and cbind it with the features data for classification.

However, using `as.factor(y)` will produce the following error:

```
Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

Am I on the right track to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `y` variable is a data.frame. You'll need to use `[[` to subset the first column out of the dataframe (even though there is presumably only a single column anyway) before you can convert to a factor data type.

```
# convert y to a factor
y <- as.factor(y[[1]])
```

Then you should be able to run your model.